# Cannot delete /usr/bin/php in macos

Tags: php, macos

I want to delete php in mac:

```
/private/etc/               sudo rm -rf php-fpm.conf.default php.ini php.ini.default
/usr/bin/               sudo rm -rf php php-config phpdoc phpize
/usr/include                sudo rm -rf php
/usr/lib                sudo rm -rf php
/usr/sbin               sudo rm -rf php-fpm
/usr/share              sudo rm -rf php
/usr/share/man/man1         sudo rm -rf php-config.1 php.1 phpize.1
/usr/share/man/man8         sudo rm -rf php-fpm.8
```

when i run

```
sudo rm -rf php php-config phpdoc phpize
```

happen:

```
rm: php: Operation not permitted
rm: php-config: Operation not permitted
rm: phpize: Operation not permitted
```

Anyone can help me? thanks a lot!

Comment: You might be better off researching how to "uninstall" PHP instead of just deleting it. (Not on a Mac so I don't know how to do it). On Linux you'd just type something like `sudo apt remove php7.1` which would remove all references, man files etc in just one command. I guess Mac also has some sort of package manager that can handle this

Answer (score 6):

To delete a file in /usr/bin/, you need to disable SIP (System Integrity Protection) by following below steps:

1. Turn off your Mac (Apple > Shut Down).
2. Hold down Command-R and press the Power button. Keep holding Command-R until the Apple logo appears.
   Wait for OS X to boot into the OS X Utilities window.
3. Choose Utilities > Terminal.
   Enter `csrutil disable`.
   Enter `reboot`.

To enable SIP again, repeating the above steps (2 first steps), enter `csrutil enable` and reboot your Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

It's system php file. You shouldn't delete it. Better install another php version with homebrew

Answer (score 1):

something like `sudo brew unlink phpxx`, where `xx` is your version number. Never delete file inside other directories then your home directory manually, unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, try this if the php version you need is already installed.

```
brew link --overwrite php@7.4
```

Comment: In my case, the problem happened because I already had the package, and re-installed it by `brew`

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything to `/usr/bin/php`.